# review form not showing - update: it was ebizmarts magemonkey!

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, review

This one is puzzling me - the review form is simply not showing on the review page

The reviews themselves are showing fine - but no form.

I have a theme set up but all the theme has is a local.xml, and that is not touching reviews at all - and neither is it changing or setting `product.info.product_additional_data`

From looking at things with my debug module, the block doesn't seem to be called at all

Things I have checked:

- My theme does not change anything related to reviews, or even that "additional info" tab
- I have no other theme installed
- reviews are enabled
- ratings are defined
- guest can leave reviews

Comment: does your theme overrides `catalog.xml` OR `review.xml`? If so, can you show here ?

Comment: check in system > configuration > system > advance  there is review module is enable or not

Comment: doesn't override catalog.xml or review.xml - it just has small tweaks in local.xml, nothing else

Comment: and yes, enabled

Answer (score 0):

Just found the culprit - the **ebizmarts mailchimp module** - putting it here in case someone else gets that issue.

It comes with a whole bunch of extra modules which I had disabled (set to "false" in the appropriate `/code/etc/modules` xml files!) because mandrill is now quite expensive so these modules are useless.

But when I looked for places that touch `product.info.product_additional_data` the only thing I could find besides the standard Magento files was `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ebizmarts/autoresponder.xml`

Now in my understanding there's no way a module which is disabled in /code/etc/modules should have its layout files processed, but when I commented out the review overrides in `autoresponder.xml` and cleared cache, the form appears

Comment: I've just been rebitten when updating magemonkey!

Comment: it is still happening on every module update