# Why the bulk update attributes is showing a blank red error message?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attributes, massaction

I'm trying to bulk update visibility of all products from **Actions > Update Attributes** under **Catalog > Products** menu.

I'm getting this error. Any Idea Why?

[image: magento bulk update error]

Comment: Check the folder var/log/ and add here, I guess that it's caused by a third-party extension.

Comment: I checked exception.log , system.log and some other logs that I created to debug some things. There is no sign related to this issue.

Comment: UPDATE: The problem caused by an extension for sure. This is verified.

I'll edit when I learn exactly which extension causes this problem.

Comment: having had the same problem, I can confirm there is nothing in the logs that help figure this out. really sloppy of the extension!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the issue have relation with the third-party extension that added this customized button "Grid Customization".

Try to disable this extension removing the XML file related to this one of the folder `app/etc/modules`.

Comment: Already tried  this. No good :/

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue, which turned out to be caused by the Ebizmarts_MailChimp extension.

It has been fixed in a recent commit, but has yet to be added to a release. https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento/issues/209

Comment: Thank you for figuring that out.
Disabling the "ecommerce" part of the extension is enough to disappear the error. Why this extension has to put its nose in every product data save is beyond me!

Although that will be the second time that the ebizmarts extension causes improbable errors that waste my time. For a year it broke the review form at each update (see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125913/review-form-not-showing-update-it-was-ebizmarts-magemonkey/125921) so I think I will plan to move away from this integration